# RMarkdown: Multiple input files in the pandoc command

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

`Pandoc` can obviously read input from multiple files. [Documentation says:](http://pandoc.org/README.html#using-pandoc):

`pandoc [options] [input-file]…`

> If multiple input files are given, pandoc will concatenate them all
>   (with blank lines between them) before parsing.

I have:

**`main.Rmd`**

```
---
output:
  pdf_document
---

After the above YAML front-matter, additional YAML input follows:

---
myparams: blabla
whatnot: testtest
---

Now the main body follows, using $myparams$ and $whatnot$ from the second YAML block...
```

**Question:**

How to separate out the second YAML block into its own file and point `rmarkdown`/`knitr` to it, so that they issue the pandoc command with two input files instead of one? Can I somehow specify that `path-to\separate.yaml` asset in the YAML front matter?

```
$pandoc main.md separate.yaml --output main.pdf`
```

**`separate.yaml`**

```
---
myparams: blabla
whatnot: testtest
---
```

**`main.Rmd`**

```
---
input-files: path-to/separate.yaml
output:
  pdf_document
---

Now the main body follows, having access to 
$myparams$ and $whatnot$ from the separate  YAML file...
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to separate out the second YAML block into its own file and point rmarkdown/knitr to it, so that they issue the pandoc command with two input files instead of one?

I had a similar problem in the past but I didn't need the YAML header so I pre-processed the files removing the YAML headers and merging the files. I suggested that you do something similar, create your own script to pre-process the files before send it to rmarkdown/knitr.

> Can I somehow specify that path-to\separate.yaml asset in the YAML front matter?

**No you can't.**

Comment: Thanks. Can you show the minimal working code that appends the `separate.yaml` file with `main.Rmd` file and processes the merged file with knitr? That would be helpful, thanks

Comment: @DanielKrizian you can use `head -n -1` to get the "begin" of `separate.yaml` and you can use `tail -n +2` to get the "end" of `main.Rmd`. Using this two commands you can easily merge the two files.